# I update a post and it creates a pingback? Any idea why?

Tags: comments

Like the title suggests if I update a post then a 'pingback' is created in as a blog post comment waiting to be approved.

Any idea why?

Thanks for all help/ suggestions.

Comment: I don't believe humanity has suffered such a problem yet, this is really weird... Have you tried to usual routine of disabling plugins and moving to the default theme?

Comment: does it create a new comment every time you update the post? is it similar to the post content? what's in your post and what's in that comment?

Comment: "the change is reflected in a blog post comment" are you saying that what was changed/updated in the post is now a comment? As in, I add a paragraph and a photo and that is now a comment, too?

Comment: Sorry to the above - I wasn't clear (and I have changed the title of the question) - the problem is that a 'pingback' is created each time I update a post..

Comment: Glad to hear it was a mistype. I was about to quit working on WordPress forever after i heard about such an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I quote a sentence from [WpBeginners](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/pingback/) about what a pingback is:

> Pingback allows you to notify other bloggers that you have linked to
> their article on your website.

So it means you probably have a link to someone else's blog, which results in a pingback each time you update or publish a post in the above circumstance.

It can be a good practice if you want to notify other bloggers about you being interested in their content, they might want to link you back, or even add your website's URL in their footer. This is one of the aspects of off-site SEO.

Answer (score 0):

As jack mentioned, it would be a great thing to get a pingback alert if someone is linking your blog post in their website. But in case if you don't want to get pingback alert, you can turn it off.

Go to **settings> Discussion> Default article setting> untick " Attempt to notify any blogs linked to from the article" and " Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks) on new articles"**

For more details on pingback you can check this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pingbacks